# How to align a text field with its title in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

[image]

The code below is producing the image above within a column:

```
  <div class="aParent">
      <div>
          <font size="8">Move:</font> 
      </div>
      <div style="float: left;">
          <input type="text" id="moveField"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Here is CSS:

I want it to look like this instead:

[image]

How do I align the two horizontally? So that "Move" is on the same line as the text field?

Comment: The font tag is deprecated. Use CSS to change the font size instead.

Comment: Please add your CSS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `.aParent` class:

```
.aParent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can change the font size to match the size of the box you want. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just put them in the same div

```
<div class="aParent">
      <div style="float: right;">
          <font size="8">Move:</font> <input type="text" id="moveField"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to look like your screenshot, make the font sizes match. Also, the `font` element is deprecated, use CSS to change the font-size instead.

```css
.move, #moveField {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<span class="move">Move:</span> <input type="text" id="moveField" value="text"  >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some padding for input div.Example:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;" class="aParent">
  <div>
      <font size="8">Move:</font> 
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top: 25px;">
      <input type="text" id="moveField"/>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `css`

```
.aParent {
    display: table;
}

.div1{
    display: table-cell;
}

.div2 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Add classes to your divs:

```
 <div class="aParent">
      <div class="div1">
          <font size="8">Move:</font> 
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
          <input type="text" id="moveField"/>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add display property to inline-block and give some height to input for align it to middle of text
`

```
<div class="aParent">
      <div style="display:inline-block">
          <font size="8">Move:</font> 
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
          <input type="text" id="moveField"/>
      </div>
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<div class="aParent">
      <div>
          <font size="6">Move:</font> 
          <input type="text" id="moveField"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#moveField{
      width: 3em;
      height: 3em;
      padding-top: 1em;
      border: 4px solid lightskyblue;
}
```